# brew install i386-elf-gcc and error:contains conflicting version recursive dependencies

Tags: macos, toolchain, i386

brew install i386-elf-gcc

==> Installing i386-elf-gcc from altkatz/gcc_cross_compilers
Error: altkatz/gcc_cross_compilers/i386-elf-gcc contains conflicting version recursive dependencies:
  gmp, gmp@4, mpfr, mpfr@2, libmpc, libmpc@0.8

View these with `brew deps --tree altkatz/gcc_cross_compilers/i386-elf-gcc`.

And the debs tree looks like:

```
altkatz/gcc_cross_compilers/i386-elf-gcc
├── gmp
├── libmpc
│   ├── gmp
│   └── mpfr
│       └── gmp
├── mpfr
│   └── gmp
└── i386-elf-binutils
```

After I installed the gmp@4,mpfr@2,libmpc@0.8,gcc49 ,the error doesn't change .

Answer (score 0):

I installed it using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php) and it worked for me:

```
sudo port install i386-elf-binutils
sudo port install i386-elf-gcc

cd /opt/local/bin
sudo ln -s i386-elf-gcc i386-elf-gcc-4.7.2
```